# Can not install pip install sphinxcontrib-openapi - "Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable"

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-sphinx

I have python 2.7.5 installed and have installed these modules sucessfully

- pip install sphinx==1.6.1
- pip install sphinxcontrib-httpdomain
- pip install sphinxcontrib.inlinesyntaxhighlight

But pip install sphinxcontrib-openapi giving errors as shown below. I have tried reading the possible solutions to this issue on web for some time now but have really not able to figure this issue out.

```
-bash-4.2$ pip install sphinxcontrib-openapi
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting sphinxcontrib-openapi
  Using cached sphinxcontrib-openapi-0.6.0.tar.gz (173 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-T5Gbq2/sphinxcontrib-openapi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-T5Gbq2/sphinxcontrib-openapi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-XiwTiv
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-T5Gbq2/sphinxcontrib-openapi/
    Complete output (46 lines):
    /tmp/easy_install-YIaJG0/setuptools_scm-6.0.1/src
    <pkg_resources.WorkingSet object at 0x7f3c06997510>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-T5Gbq2/sphinxcontrib-openapi/setup.py", line 57, in <module>
        namespace_packages=['sphinxcontrib'],
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 265, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs.pop('setup_requires'))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 289, in fetch_build_eggs
        parse_requirements(requires), installer=self.fetch_build_egg
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 618, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 862, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 874, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 339, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 623, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 653, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 849, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1130, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1115, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 69, in run_setup
        lambda: execfile(
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 120, in run
        return func()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 71, in <lambda>
        {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
      File "setup.py", line 52, in <module>
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
      File "setup.py", line 29, in scm_config
        setup_requires=[
      File "/tmp/easy_install-YIaJG0/setuptools_scm-6.0.1/src/setuptools_scm/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
      File "/tmp/easy_install-YIaJG0/setuptools_scm-6.0.1/src/setuptools_scm/config.py", line 6, in <module>
      File "/tmp/easy_install-YIaJG0/setuptools_scm-6.0.1/src/setuptools_scm/utils.py", line 41
        print(*k)
              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.3.3; however, version 20.3.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
-bash-4.2$ ^C
```

Comment: There is a syntax error because the code you are trying to install is Python 3. Please take heed of the  warning at the top of the output you present.

Comment: Here it says `python_requires=">=3.6"`: https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/openapi/blob/master/setup.py#L61